# Good decision for EnableEventValidation exception

Tags: asp.net

I fill dropdownlist in js-code and try to save selected value but every time I get exception "Invalid postback or callback argument....". I've read many blog posts and answers but it's not clear for me. I can set EnableEventValidation to false but it's bad way I think. I've read about

```
ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(JSfilledDDList.UniqueID)
```

but it doesn't decide this problem. Could you give me good decision of this problem?

Comment: I had a similar situation and I used client side `html list-option` with server side `hidden-field` and set the hidden field value on index changed.

Comment: Is there some decision for server dropdownlist?

Comment: because I don't wanted to use `EnableEventValidation`. It is not suggested by the people.

Answer (score 0):

You made good decision here.. **Do not disable the *EnableEventValidation***. or You'll end up inviting security vulnerabilities.
You must use the UpdatePanel to sync the items you're adding in the List at client side with server side. Which is basically sticking with regular postback. This would be a solution in your case.

Comment: Could I disable validation only for this element?

Comment: Nope, There's no way for disabling it for single control.

Comment: But what this method ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(uniqueId) really do?

Comment: I think would give you Idea what you're looking for: http://chuchuva.com/pavel/2009/12/how-to-use-clientscriptmanager-registerforeventvalidation-method/

Comment: if I set EnableEventValidation to false what problems I get?